# ElasticSearch Querying and OR

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nosql

Here's my mapping

```
{
  "app" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "patient" : {
        "properties" : {
          "LastName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "consultations" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "deleted" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "diagnosis" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "documentDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "firstName" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "lastName" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "middleName" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "prescriptions" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "firstName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "gender" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "lastName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "middleName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "owner" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "patientPin" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Then let's say I have this data


{
   "id":"21",
   "firstName":"Scrappy",
   "patientPin":"2012010000000021",
   "middleName":"D",
   "consultations":[
      {
         "id":null,
         "prescriptions":[
            "GADOTERIC Acid DOTAREM"
         ],
         "diagnosis":[
            "Kawasaki's Disease",
            "Alcohol Intoxication"
         ],
         "documentDate":"2014-07-31T13:19:00.000+08:00",
         "deleted":false,
         "lastName":"Doo",
         "firstName":"Scrappy",
         "middleName":"D"
      }
   ],
   "owner":"TENANT1",
   "gender":"FEMALE",
   "lastName":"Doo"
}

{
   "id":"100066",
   "firstName":"Kyel ",
   "patientPin":"201408000001",
   "middleName":"John ",
   "consultations":[
      {
         "id":null,
         "prescriptions":[

         ],
         "diagnosis":[
            "headache"
         ],
         "documentDate":"2014-08-05T10:10:00.000+08:00",
         "deleted":false,
         "lastName":"David",
         "firstName":"Mika",
         "middleName":"John "
      }
   ],
   "owner":"TENANT1",
   "gender":"MALE",
   "lastName":"David"
}
```

How do I query patients that has consultations that has a "headache" OR "Alcohol Intoxication"?

Comment: Do you need the complete Java application?

Comment: if you can provide the Java client query equivalent, please do so

Answer (score 0):

For your result I am suggesting you to use filter.

You can achieve this using,

For or, terms filter match document with any of value provided (which means does or for values)

```
client.prepareSearch("app").setTypes("patient").setPostFilter(
                FilterBuilders.termsFilter("consultations.diagnosis","headache","Alcohol Intoxication")
        );
```

For and,

```
client.prepareSearch("app").setTypes("patient").setPostFilter(
        FilterBuilders.andFilter(
                FilterBuilders.termsFilter("consultations.diagnosis","headache"),
                FilterBuilders.termsFilter("consultations.diagnosis","Alcohol Intoxication")
        )
);
```

For this, Any value you want to filter should be index : not_analyzed . 
try learning [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org).

Comment: I am trying to I just can't figure it out how. Why is it on the must? and not in the should? isn't it an OR operator?also I am trying to build a dynamic querying. also what if I want to search for consultations that has headache and Alcohol Intoxication?

Comment: In the above quey, termsQuery() does matching "headache" or "Alcohol Intoxication" , must ensure one should at-least do. You can find difference in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html .

Comment: I see, but what if I want to search for consultations with headache and Alcohol Intoxication? how do I go about that with the existing query you have given?

Comment: I've tried both but none of them seemed to work. I am querying a nested type.